# Solve the equation

Tags: riddle

Requested by some to vacate
in time I could pack and migrate

Don't think too hard, just differently
don't link me with discrepancy

Laugh at the answer you will say
enter the mind but will I stay

Comment: May I politely request a title change? When seeing this title (and tag), I assumed it was a math-based riddle. Finding out it was just a meta-riddle about riddles having nothing to do with math or equations was quite the letdown. If there's actually a reason for it to be titled "Solve the Equation" that I'm not seeing, please say so, but nothing in the question or accepted answer indicates that to me.

Comment: In my opinion although if its not recieved well I'll change it. Is based upon the answer to the riddle. consider those who enjoy riddles as A and those who believe them to be redundant as Z. what does A+Z= mean in terms of the state of puzzling.SE. Remember its just an opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A riddle on puzzling.SE?

Given the current ... ahem ... tense political situation on this site, I think this is the answer.

*Requested by some to vacate 

 in time I could pack and migrate*

> Some people on puzzling.SE want to see all riddles taken off the site. But it would be possible (I suggested this in the Green Llama!) to set up say riddling.SE and migrate all the riddles to that new site.

*Don't think too hard, just differently*

> To solve a riddle you often need to 'think differently' from your current mindset.

*don't link me with discrepancy*

> Riddles don't necessarily have a discrepancy with what this site should be about!

*Laugh at the answer you will say 

 enter the mind but will I stay*

> The answer to a riddle might be funny; it enters your mind once you know it, but might not stay when you move on to the next riddle.

If this is right, then excellent question, Oblongamous!

Answer (score 5):

> The first character of each line form the acrostic RIDDLE.

Comment: Good catch! But what's the answer?

Comment: Are you assuming the rest of the riddle is almost pointless, or can you link them to Riddle as the acrostic implies.

Comment: Well, the OP has not marked this as correct, so obviously that was not the answer, and the rest of the riddle must be meaningful in some way, but I don't know what way.

Comment: Well, it kind of was correct...